# How to convert hql to sql and apply filters on it?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I call this method to convert hql query to sql:

```
public String toSql(String hqlQueryText) {
    if (hqlQueryText != null && hqlQueryText.trim().length() > 0) {
        QueryTranslatorFactory translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
        SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory;
        QueryTranslator translator = translatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(hqlQueryText, hqlQueryText, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, factory, null);
        translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
        return translator.getSQLString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and I have this filter in `.hbm.xml` file of domain class:

`<filter name="userAuthorize" condition="some sql query here" />`

but I don't know how I should tell hibernate to apply this filter when converting from hql to sql.

Assume that I call above method like this:

```
public Session getSession() {
    try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

public List<DomainClass> getAll() {
    String hql = " some hql query ";
    Session session = getSession();
    String sql = toSql(hql);

    return session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a great Idea. But maybe It helps.

HQL and SQL have some differences, for instance with join , 'on' is used in SQL and 'with' is used in HQL.
So maybe you can use list of words that are unique to HQL and check for them  in your String using

hql.contains("with") or hql.indexOf("with").

Answer (score 0):

It is not the responsibility of the QueryTranslator to apply filters. Also, filters don't get applied to native SQL.

It looks like you just want to execute the HQL query? There is no need to have it translated to SQL first:

```
public List<DomainClass> getAll() {
    String hql = " some hql query ";
    return session.createQuery(hql).list();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to execute the simple hql query, i wrote it simple to explain my problem shortly.
There isn't any way to apply filter when converting hql to sql, may be everything instead of QueryTranslator?

Comment: Hi Rasool, your question is titled "Hibernate QueryTranslator does not apply filter". I gave you the right answer: it doesn't by design. You should accept it and create a new question if you have a different question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i changed the question title, could you help me to resolve this problem?